# CP-SAT to balance task assignment

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears,
I'm wondering if CP-SAT as any built-in function that allow me to balance the number of tasks assigned to the users.
Now I'm calculating the variance and I'm minimizing it in the objective function, so it would be great to have the possibility to calculate the variance with a built-in function, but I'm wondering if I have alternatives.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no alternative.

If the number of tasks and of workers is fixed. You can compute the average, and using an epsilon, add the following constraints:

```
for all workers:
  model.Add(sum(assigned_tasks) <= average + epsilon)
  model.Add(sum(assigned_tasks) >= average - epsilon)

model.Minimize(epsilon)
```

This is less precise, but much faster.

Comment: to minimize epslon I need to find epsolon as a function of the operator per task decisions, Am I right?

Comment: could be a global epsilon, could be one per operator, and minimize the sum of epsilons

Comment: Not sure I understood. If I have 3 workers and 9 tasks for example how epsilon function should be?. Thanks

Comment: Constraint each worker to have between 3-epsilon and 3+epsilon tasks assigned to him, and minimize epsilon.